# ORM Prisma saves date in UTC by default

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, prisma

I have a backend with Express, and I use Prisma as ORM. The database is Mysql. The problem is in a column 'init_hour' of type Time (Mysql) that when saving the data, if I receive 10:20 it saves 9:20 (time zone +1). Apparently Prisma saves by default in UTC but I don't know how to change that option.

`Mysql  init_hour   time`

Prisma
`init_hour       DateTime?      @db.Time(0)`

What I am currently doing before saving 'init _hour' in the backend is:

```
const currentHour= new Date();
currentHour.setHours(10, 20, 0);
```

Does anyone have any clues as to where things might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prisma saves by default in UTC, true, and currently it's not possible to change it. [Here's the GitHub issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3292) for tracking timezone support.

Saving in UTC is good practice in any case, as it consistent and it is straight-forward to convert to any other desired timezone when displaying the data.

Comment: Thank you very much Perttu. It is true, there was confusion on the difference between the Node-RED and Prisma queries.

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted out. If my answer helped you, I would appreciate it if you could mark the question as answered.